# OOPs Method Restriction

Tags: c#, oop

Today I had attended a interview for skill set asp.net,c#,Sql

Interview Person asked a question as below

there is a class with two methods.

```
public class employee 
{    
    public int Getsalary()
    {    
        //Code logic     
    } 

    public string GetEmployee()
    {     
        //Code Logic     
    }     
}
```

Question is 
any new client creating object for this class should not have access for getsalary method. 
existing client creating object for this class should have access for both methods.

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean "existing code should still work, but new code should not"?

Comment: You can't have different access restrictions for differenrt consumers of a class.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "a client creating object for this class".

Comment: just say "well i suppose you could use reflection" that answer all questions

Comment: they want to restrict the access for some clients who is accessing this class.

Comment: I guess you could change the method access modifiers to `internal` and use the `[InternalsVisibleToAttribute]` attribute to make the methods visible to friend assemblies (the existing code). But it seems unlikely this would be what they were asking.

Comment: I don't know what the question is asking, but if it is asking what I suspect they are asking, then these interviewers are not people I would like to work for :)

Comment: I think "InternalsVisibleToAttribute " will be answer  for this. thanks for providing solution quickly

Comment: Doesn't make sense... Well, as long as it answers you question :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe the interviewer was getting at using the [Obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) annotation.  I believe flagging a method [Obsolete] will not break existing applications using the method (unless they’re edited and recompiled), but you can force a compiler error when new code tries to use it like so:

```
[Obsolete("This method is deprecated.  Use Foo instead.", true)]
```